# How to execute procedure in toad?

Tags: oracle, toad

I have a oracle sql script with following contents:
A Function and 3 procedures.
One procedure (MAIN) internally will call the other 2 procs and the function.

Now through TOAD, how can I execute or call the the MAIN procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
EXECUTE main;
```

If you want it in a PL/SQL block for some reason:

```
BEGIN
   main;
END;
```

Of course, this assumes that you have direct access to the main procedure itself.

Is that what you meant or have I missed something?

If I have then this might be helpful:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31544&seqNum=10

Comment: Thanks. Instead of typing EXECUTE main; can we do it using mouse only (using TOAD menu options somehow)